# xml sitemap forbidden for access via nginx

Tags: nginx

My nginx site configuraton:

```
upstream nodeName {
    server serverIp:7050;
    server serverIp:7049 backup;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    gzip_types application/x-javascript text/css;
    access_log /pathToLogs/log.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://nodeName/;
    }
    location ~ ^/(min/|images/|bootstrap/|ckeditor/|img/|javascripts/|apple-touch-icon-ipad.png|apple-touch-icon-ipad3.png|apple-touch-icon-iphone.png|apple-touch-icon-iphone4.png|generated/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico|xml/) {
          root /pathToSite/appdirectory-build;
          access_log off;
          expires max;
        }
}
```

I want to get `sitemap.xml` by url http://example.com/xml/sitemap.xml but it gives me

```
403 Forbidden

nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

## Update

In `nginx` error log file:

```
2014/10/09 [error] 16094#0: *49762240 open() "/pathToSite/appdirectory-build/xml/sitemapCallEn.xml" failed (13: Permission denied), client: Ip, server: domain.com, request: "GET /xml/sitemapCallEn.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "domain"
```

How to change permission and allow to open xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Look into nginx error log. You will find answer there. It's file permission issue likely